# Different behavior of location.reload() in Firefox and Google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I am calling location.reload() while select the drop-down option for changing the language

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeLanguage(){  
    location.reload();
}

function loadPage() {
    var language = document.getElementById("lang").value;
    alert(language);    
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadPage()">

<select name="lang" id="lang" onchange="changeLanguage()">
        <option value="english">English</option>
        <option value="hindi">हिंदी</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

If i run this page in Firefox it alert which one i am selecting. This is what i want. But if i run this page in Google chrome it gives first option always.

I think while loading, drop-down get reloaded so getting selected value is first option.

Actually i want to get selected one even page load also.

I have applied this concept for different purpose, for simplification i have return this simple code.

Comment: you better save current lang value in local storage for example, cause if user reload page manualy with ctrl+f5, selected value will be lost

Comment: Are you using a server-side language?

Comment: @Mooseman No. I am not using serverside language, using only HTML5, CSS and JS

Comment: @kpblc, Ok i will try to keep it in cookies.

Comment: @kpblc, thanks i have solved by adding cookies in local storage, see my answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by adding cookies :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeLanguage(lang){
    setCookie("flip_book_lang", lang, 7);
    location.reload();
}

function loadPage(lang) {
    var language = document.getElementById("lang").value;
    var curr_lang = getCookie("flip_book_lang");
    document.getElementById("lang").value = curr_lang;
    alert(curr_lang);   
}

//Source : w3schools, 023-09-2014 http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1){ 
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);        
        }
    }
    return "";
}
function removeCookie(cname){
    document.cookie = cname + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadPage()">

<select name="lang" id="lang" onchange="changeLanguage(this.value)">
        <option value="english">English</option>
        <option value="hindi">हिंदी</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```